# parallel block in algorithm overleaf

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms, algorithm2e

One part of my algorithm is done in parallel, for that, I have a block in my algorithm, but I can not show it properly. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered,ruled,longend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\DontPrintSemicolon 
\SetKwBlock{DoParallel}{do in parallel}{end}

\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\STATE \DoParallel{
\FOR{ $1\leq i \leq Epoch$}
    \STATE Do the 
\ENDFOR
\FOR{ $1\leq i \leq Epoch$}
\STATE Do the 1;
\ENDFOR}
\end{algorithmic}\label{}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: here is the figure]

Any other response which is related to the parallel in the algorithm is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing two different packages for algorithms, but it's hard to tell, what is going on, since your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing (at least) two different packages for typesetting algorithms. I suggest, you stick to one of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered,ruled,longend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwBlock{DoParallel}{do in parallel}{end}
    \DoParallel{
        \For{$1\leq i \leq$ Epoch}{
            Do the
        }
        \For{$1\leq i \leq$ Epoch}{
            Do the 1;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}\label{oursmc}
\end{document}
```

[image]